# Highcharts keyboard navigation not working

Tags: javascript, highcharts

Highcharts keyboard navigation is not working for me. I am using it exactly in the same way mentioned in API docs.

<https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/accessibility.keyboardNavigation.seriesNavigation

This is my fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/gopalsingh0707/1ko2pdav/35/

```
 plotOptions: { series: { allowPointSelect: true }},

  accessibility: {
    keyboardNavigation: {
        enabled:true,
        
        seriesNavigation:{
          mode:'normal' 
          }
        
        
    }
},
```

The focus is also not going to chart when the chart loads. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Navigation works fine.

In the demo you attached, I can normally navigate using the keyboard. However, you must pay attention that in JSFiddle you need to focus on the iframe with the result, otherwise you will be navigating the interface of the page. Just click in the upper left corner of the result (white window) and press `TAB`.

Or if you reproduce this demo in a pure HTML file, you should have no problems navigating the chart.

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer. Yes, it is working fine. Do we have any way, when the chart loads, the series gets focus automatically.  Also I need one more help. Like we can capture click event (Highcharts.addEvent(Highcharts.Point, 'click', function (e) { } ) in Javascript. In the same way, can we capture keyboard event too in Javascript? I need to perform some actions too in chart when I move the points using arrow keys.